# How can I fix my unbearably slow NFS linux server?

Tags: linux, raid, nfs, mount

I'm currently struggling with an extremely slow server providing home directories through NFS, and I cannot figure out the origin of the problem. It's all running on Nixos, but I don't think that's important.

Here is the setup : I have a Dell server with a H330 raid card, and 3 hard-drives : one for the system (`/sda`), and two in RAID 1 for users accounts (`/sdc`). It is only used for serving home directories. The partition `/sdc1` of the RAID disk is mounted on `/home/lan`, on `/sda1` and is exported through NFS. There is also a `swap` partition on `/sda2`.

The `/etc/fstab` looks like:

```
/dev/sda1 / ext4 x-initrd.mount 0 1
/dev/sdc1 /home/lan ext4 defaults 0 2
```

And the nfs export is

```
/home/lan   192.168.1.0/24(insecure,rw,async,no_subtree_check)
```

I also have up to 50 clients connecting to this server for student machines. The clients mount `/home/lan` and login is done using LDAP.

It seems that the NFS part is fine, for instance, running `nfsstat` on the server :

```
Server rpc stats:
calls      badcalls   badfmt     badauth    badclnt
19836893   0          0          0          0
```

I think that the problem comes from the disk configuration. In particular, the server is spending most is time writing on `/sda` and not `/sdc` (here is the iostat output)

```
Device      tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
sda       10,10         0,79        73,48         0,00    2004798  185360634          0
sdc        0,50         0,08         8,56         0,00     203605   21587308          0
```

And `btop` confirms that `/sda` is used much more than `/sdc`. But, I repeat, there is almost with running on this server, it is only devoted to serving `/home/lan` so basically, most of the read/write should regard `/sdc` and not `/sda`.

Does anyone have an idea of what goes wrong and how I can fix that?

PS: `iostat -x 3 3` yields

```
Linux 6.1.31 (scribe)   26/09/2023  _x86_64_    (6 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0,05    0,00    0,05    0,78    0,00   99,12

Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz     f/s f_await  aqu-sz  %util
sda              0,08      0,83     0,03  23,78    4,61    10,08   10,15     74,73     5,57  35,45    6,32     7,36    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    1,77   20,69    0,10   4,58
sdb              0,01      0,10     0,00   0,00    0,28    15,34    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00
sdc              0,00      0,11     0,00   4,00   42,29    38,16    0,55      9,27     0,82  60,03    1,62    16,93    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,03


avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0,06    0,00    0,17    2,33    0,00   97,45

Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz     f/s f_await  aqu-sz  %util
sda              0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00   17,33    158,67    18,67  51,85    8,06     9,15    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    6,67   18,30    0,26  14,17
sdb              0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00
sdc              0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00


avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0,11    0,00    0,17    4,28    0,00   95,44

Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz     f/s f_await  aqu-sz  %util
sda              0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00   26,67    256,00    30,67  53,49    9,75     9,60    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00   10,00   23,07    0,49  26,40
sdb              0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00
sdc              0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00
```

Following the comments, I have tried several tools such as `iotop` (very useful!) and reading the output of `journalctl`. I have found a first problem, excessive logging from OpenLDAP. I have removed that as this part works correctly. I'm now left with...

```
sept. 29 11:44:43 scribe rpc.mountd[729895]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3573a65167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:44:43 scribe rpc.mountd[725638]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3573a65167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:44:43 scribe rpc.mountd[729900]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3573a65167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:44:44 scribe rpc.mountd[729895]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3573c65167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:44:44 scribe rpc.mountd[725638]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3573c65167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:44:44 scribe rpc.mountd[729900]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3573c65167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:44:45 scribe rpc.mountd[729895]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3573c65167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:44:45 scribe rpc.mountd[729900]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3573c65167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:44:45 scribe rpc.mountd[725638]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3573c65167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:00 scribe rpc.mountd[729895]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3575765167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:00 scribe rpc.mountd[729900]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3575765167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:00 scribe rpc.mountd[725638]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3575765167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:00 scribe rpc.mountd[729895]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3575765167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:00 scribe rpc.mountd[729900]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3575765167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:00 scribe rpc.mountd[725638]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3575765167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:11 scribe rpc.mountd[729895]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3577265167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:11 scribe rpc.mountd[725638]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3577265167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:11 scribe rpc.mountd[729900]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3577265167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:11 scribe rpc.mountd[729895]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3577465167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:11 scribe rpc.mountd[729900]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3577465167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:11 scribe rpc.mountd[729900]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3577265167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:11 scribe rpc.mountd[729895]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3577265167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:11 scribe rpc.mountd[725638]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3577265167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
```

This is the entries of journalctl for a single client. And I have between 20 and 50 of them!
But I don't know how to find why there are so many attaching and detaching, and even if it is normal.

Comment: Could you please add the output of `iostat -x 3 3` ?

Comment: What do you mean by not readable? You can edit the question and add the output of the command.

Comment: First, it seems that `journald` causes all the r/w on `/sda`.

Comment: To see what is being written time something like: `journalctl | tail -10`, which will show the last 10 lines that were written, hopefully containing part of the problem.

Comment: read more on **journald**, in the long answer part here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1082910/274445

Comment: Ok, journald shows mainly two things :
- slapd makes A LOT of entries,
- rpc.mountd attaching and detaching clients.
I'll read more about journald this evening, but I think that I can make slapd a bit quieter.

Comment: To not guess but be sure I can suggest to stare to `iotop` output for some period of time, to catch out what processes are doing I/O. Or, use accounting like atop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: What do you precisely means with *extremely slow*? Can you explain which kind of operations are slow?

Comment: Actually, it is now faster than it was, due to some improvement that were suggested. But, basically, before that, it could take up to 10 seconds to save a file or list the files in a directory. And saving a file can still take a couple of seconds.