# Is it normal that rpc.mountd keeps on attaching and detaching clients?

Tags: nfs

As a follow-up from [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1144496/how-can-i-fix-my-unbearably-slow-nfs-linux-server),

I have a server (using Nixos) and providing home directories through nfs on my school network, and there is A LOT of attaching and detaching. Here is an excerpt of the `journalctl` log, where I have selected the entries of a **single** client:

```
sept. 29 11:44:25 scribe rpc.mountd[729895]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3572965167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:44:39 scribe rpc.mountd[729895]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3573a65167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:44:39 scribe rpc.mountd[729900]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3573a65167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:44:39 scribe rpc.mountd[725638]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3573a65167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:44:43 scribe rpc.mountd[729895]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3573a65167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:44:43 scribe rpc.mountd[725638]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3573a65167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:44:43 scribe rpc.mountd[729900]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3573a65167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:44:44 scribe rpc.mountd[729895]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3573c65167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:44:44 scribe rpc.mountd[725638]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3573c65167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:44:44 scribe rpc.mountd[729900]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3573c65167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:44:45 scribe rpc.mountd[729895]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3573c65167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:44:45 scribe rpc.mountd[729900]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3573c65167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:44:45 scribe rpc.mountd[725638]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3573c65167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:00 scribe rpc.mountd[729895]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3575765167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:00 scribe rpc.mountd[729900]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3575765167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:00 scribe rpc.mountd[725638]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3575765167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:00 scribe rpc.mountd[729895]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3575765167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:00 scribe rpc.mountd[729900]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3575765167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:00 scribe rpc.mountd[725638]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3575765167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:11 scribe rpc.mountd[729895]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3577265167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:11 scribe rpc.mountd[725638]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3577265167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:11 scribe rpc.mountd[729900]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3577265167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:11 scribe rpc.mountd[729895]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3577465167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:11 scribe rpc.mountd[729900]: v4.2 client attached: 0x96b3577465167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:11 scribe rpc.mountd[729900]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3577265167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:11 scribe rpc.mountd[729895]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3577265167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
sept. 29 11:45:11 scribe rpc.mountd[725638]: v4.2 client detached: 0x96b3577265167ddb from "192.168.1.197:1005"
```

and I have from 20 up to 50 of such clients. It generates a lot of logging.

Is this behaviour normal, and if not, how can I fix it?

Comment: What makes you think it's the server that's detaching clients? A very common configuration for NFS clients (especially with AutoFS) is to unmount remote mounts after a time of inactivity and remounting them when they get accessed.

Comment: Although the timestamps in this specific case do not indicate this case. Have you checked the corresponding client logs?

Comment: I don't know if it is the server or the client that initiates the detachment. It's just that I have discovered this on the server's journal. And I haven't found the reason for this. No trace of this on the client (the journal makes no mention of this, and I don't know where else to look), and there is an idle timeout of 600 so that detachment should not occur that often !